# Prime generating Python code using C.P. Willans formula

Tags: python, primes

I wrote a prime generating code in Python, and it produces correct results. However when i want to print 8th prime I get an `OverflowError`:

```
sum += floor(pow(cos(pi * (factorial(j - 1) + 1) / j), 2))
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

I tried to use decimal module, but I cant fix the problem.

Code:

```
from math import floor, cos, pi, factorial


def nth_prime(n):
    if isinstance(n, int) and n > 0:
        end_sum = 0
        for i in range(1, 2 ** n + 1):

            sum = 0
            for j in range(1, i + 1):
                sum += floor(pow(cos(pi * (factorial(j - 1) + 1) / j), 2))

            end_sum += floor(pow((n / sum), (1 / n)))

        return end_sum + 1

    else:
        raise Exception("Enter a positive integer")


print(nth_prime(8))
```

I tried using decimal module, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Your `factorial()` result exceeds 1.7976931348623157e+308; hence the error as this is the maximum float value.

Comment: math formulas are not necessarily aimed at efficient computation. For example, this one is not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in this line:

```
floor(pow(cos(pi * (factorial(j - 1) + 1) / j)
```

You could use the periodicity of cos(1π) = cos(3π) etc. and analogously for the even multiples of pi. So subtract all multiples of 2π (360°) from the argument, (factorial(j - 1) + 1) / j before calculating cos.